# Ошибка object has no attribute

Tags: python

Написал такую программу. Не пойму почему выходит ошибка AttributeError: 'CellPhone' object has no attribute '_CellPhone__retail_price'
Вот программа

**Класс CellPhone содержит данные о сотовом телефоне.**

```
class CellPhone:

    # Метод init инициализирует атрибуты.

    def __init__(self, manufact, model, price):
        self.__manufact = manufact
        self.__model = model
        self.__price = price

    # Метод set_manufact принимает аргумент для
    # производителя телефона.

    def set_manufact (self, manufact):
        self.__manufact = manufact

    # Метод set_model принимает аргумент для
    # номера модели телефона.

    def set_model (self, model):
        self.__model = model

    # Метод set_retail_price принимает аргумент для
    # розничной цены телефона.

    def set_retail_price(self, price):
        self.__retail_price = price

    # Метод get_manufact возвращает
    # производителя телефона.

    def get_manufact(self):
        return self.__manufact

    # Метод get_model возвращает
    # номер модели телефона.

    def get_model(self):
        return self.__model

    # Метод get retail_price возвращает
    # розничную цену телефона.

    def get_retail_price(self):
        return self.__retail_price
```

**Эта программа тестирует класс CellPhone.**

```
import cellphone


def main():
    
    # Получить данные о телефоне.
    man = input('Введите производителя: ')
    mod = input('Ведите номер: ')
    retail = int(input('Введите розничную цену: '))

    # Создать экземпляр класса CellPhone
    phone = cellphone.CellPhone(man, mod, retail)

    # Показать введенные данные.
    print('Вот введенные вами данные: ')
    print('Производитель:', phone.get_manufact())
    print('Номер модели: ', phone.get_model())
    print('Розничная цена: $', phone.get_retail_price(), sep='')

main()
```

Comment: текст ошибки полностью, пожалуйста

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Project 07.02.21\ML\test_class_celphone.py", line 20, in <module>
    main()
  File "E:\Project 07.02.21\ML\test_class_celphone.py", line 18, in main
    print('Розничная цена: $', phone.get_retail_price(), sep='')
  File "E:\Project 07.02.21\ML\cellphone.py", line 46, in get_retail_price
    return self.__retail_price
AttributeError: 'CellPhone' object has no attribute '_CellPhone__retail_price'

Comment: Вы не присвоили значение атрибуту `__retail_price` и пробете его читать. Вероятно в конструкторе должно было быть `self.__retail_price = price`

Answer (score 1):

```py
    def __init__(self, manufact, model, price):
        self.__manufact = manufact
        self.__model = model
        self.__price = price
             ^^^^^^^

...

    def get_retail_price(self):
        return self.__retail_price
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Вы выставляете поле `self.__price`, а читаете `self.__retail_price`. А `set_` методы, где имя поля правильное, вы в этом коде не используете.